# How to plot two columns of a pandas data frame using points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to plot values from one column versus the values from another column. Fortunately, there is `plot` method associated with the dataframes that seems to do what I need:

```py
df.plot(x='col_name_1', y='col_name_2')
```

Unfortunately, it looks like among the plot styles (listed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) after the `kind` parameter), there are not points. I can use lines or bars or even density but not points. Is there a work around that can help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can specify the `style` of the plotted line when calling [`df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html?highlight=plot#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
df.plot(x='col_name_1', y='col_name_2', style='o')
```

The `style` argument can also be a `dict` or `list`, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : np.random.rand(10),
     'two' : np.random.rand(10)}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.plot(style=['o','rx'])
```

All the accepted style formats are listed in the documentation of [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

[image: Output]

Comment: If you're not able to see multiple column lines / points, then check the `dtypes` of the dataframe and convert it from `object` to numeric columns. This issue wasted at least a few hours for me.

Answer (score 95):

For this (and most plotting) I would not rely on the Pandas wrappers to matplotlib. Instead, just use matplotlib directly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['col_name_1'], df['col_name_2'])
plt.show() # Depending on whether you use IPython or interactive mode, etc.
```

and remember that you can access a NumPy array of the column's values with `df.col_name_1.values` for example.

I ran into trouble using this with Pandas default plotting in the case of a column of Timestamp values with millisecond precision. In trying to convert the objects to `datetime64` type, I also discovered a nasty issue: < [Pandas gives incorrect result when asking if Timestamp column values have attr astype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350364/pandas-gives-incorrect-result-when-asking-if-timestamp-column-values-have-attr-a) >.

Answer (score 11):

`Pandas` uses `matplotlib` as a library for basic plots. The easiest way in your case will using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#creating sample data 
sample_data={'col_name_1':np.random.rand(20),
      'col_name_2': np.random.rand(20)}
df= pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
df.plot(x='col_name_1', y='col_name_2', style='o')
```

[image]

However, I would recommend to use `seaborn` as an alternative solution if you want have more customized plots while not going into the basic level of `matplotlib.` In this case you the solution will be following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

#creating sample data 
sample_data={'col_name_1':np.random.rand(20),
      'col_name_2': np.random.rand(20)}
df= pd.DataFrame(sample_data)
sns.scatterplot(x="col_name_1", y="col_name_2", data=df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Now in latest pandas you can directly use df.plot.scatter function

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5.1, 3.5, 0], [4.9, 3.0, 0], [7.0, 3.2, 1],
                   [6.4, 3.2, 1], [5.9, 3.0, 2]],
                  columns=['length', 'width', 'species'])
ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                      y='width',
                      c='DarkBlue')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html