# How to plot the difference between data and a function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data set of x,y values in a file called values.txt like so:

```
1  32432.4323
2  23432.1143
.
.
.
999 1111.23432
```

I also have a function f(x), 2*x^2+1

I'd like to plot the difference curve between the function and the y values. Something like this:

```
1  32432.4323 - f(1)
2  23432.1143 - f(2)
.
.
.
999 1111.23432 - f(999)
```

I can do it by calculating the difference and placing into a separate file values_diff.txt and loading that into matplotlib, but I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic way of doing this in matplotlib that doesn't require the explicit use of a second file,

Comment: There is no need to save in a seperate txt file. You can just plot the obtained difference values against your x values. Meaning, the data that you want to save you can plot it with mpl.

Comment: Matplotlib is not for that (it's just for plotting). Surely you need to look [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)

Comment: @StijnVanDaele  would it be possible to provide a simple example?

Comment: @lbellomo You can plot functions in matplotlib, and you can plot data, i was hoping you could simply do both without having to resort to other methods.

Comment: My answer is an example of how easy it is to waste effort when you don't ask the question author to specify what they have tried themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not averse to writing code.:)

Create one vector for the x-values, one for the y-values, then one for the differences between the y's and the values of the functions. In this code, I've provided dummy values for the missing y-values. Then simply plot the y-values against the x-values first, the difference-values against the x-values next.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x: 2*x**2 +1

x = list(range(1,1000))
y = [32432.4323, 23432.1143] +[23432.1132-10*k for k in range(1,997)]+ [1111.23432]

diffs=[]
for an_x, a_y in zip(x,y):
    diffs.append(a_y-f(an_x))

plt.plot(x, y, 'r-')
plt.plot(x, diffs, 'b-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for the example, that's what I'm pretty much doing now, I'd hoped there'd be a way to do it without the need to do the diff external to matplotlib, and instead use it's expression interface.

Answer (score 1):

I will not write the code for you but this will help you out

First your txt file into pandas:
[Load data from txt with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546739/load-data-from-txt-with-pandas)

Next your do the subtraction by using the apply function:
[How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

and finally you plot them:
[How to plot two columns of a pandas data frame using points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812978/how-to-plot-two-columns-of-a-pandas-data-frame-using-points)

Kind regards,
Stijn

Comment: using `apply` is likely unnecessary, and honestly `pandas` is really overkill. Just `numpy` or even vanilla python should work easily enough.

Comment: I'm currently using a solution like that, I used to the term "2nd file" as a means to enquire about a solution that didn't require a 2nd form of storage. oh well, I guess it's not possible - thanks for the attempt.

Comment: No, you literally referred to "values_diff.txt". But no, mpl can not do the subtraction for you.