# How to deal with column gaps? Python Plots

Tags: python

I am trying to plot this but my data set has spaces. So how do I do it without removing spaces?

```
iris.plot(kind="scatter", x="sepal length", y="sepal width")
```

Comment: That's not doing what you expect.  In that call, `x` and `y` are the data points to be plotted, NOT the labels.   Where are your arrays of data points?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot two columns of a pandas data frame using points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812978/how-to-plot-two-columns-of-a-pandas-data-frame-using-points). Please consider checking [this tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/04_plotting.html) as well.